# Cypher / neo4j: Too many neighbours

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to explore the results which one of my cypher queries returns. I'd like to do that in a visual way, so neo4j's built-in browser comes quite handy. I've got a query which returns 9 nodes. One of them has the ID 318. When I doubleclick this node 318, my browser complains "Sorry! Too many neighbours". However, that node 318 has only 56 neighbours:

```
 match a-[r]-b where id(a)=318 return count(r), count(b)

 count(r)  count(b)
 56        56
```

:config seems OK to me:

```
    {
    "cmdchar": ":",
    "endpoint": {
    "console": "/db/manage/server/console",
    "jmx": "/db/manage/server/jmx/query",
    "rest": "/db/data",
    "cypher": "/db/data/cypher",
    "transaction": "/db/data/transaction"
    },
    "host": "",
    "maxExecutionTime": 3600,
    "heartbeat": 60,
    "maxFrames": 50,
    "maxHistory": 100,
    "maxNeighbours": 100,
    "maxNodes": 1000,
    "maxRows": 1000,
    "maxRawSize": 5000,
    "scrollToTop": true
}
```

The old interface `http://localhost:7474/webadmin` is able to display 318's neighbours, but its visualization is not quite like `http://localhost:7474/browser/`.

Anybody know why neo4j is whining? The other posts on this topic here in stackoverflow didn't really point to an answer, only to alternative visualization tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [related neo4j issue](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/1517) that has been closed without a fix. From that issue's comments, it seems that the limit cannot be configured, and it does not look like the collaborators are interested in addressing this.

Comment: Pity. I'll have to review other visualization tools then. Thanks, cybersam!